# Android Studio:Send notification to another device when this device trigger certain condition

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification

I'm new to Android and using Android Studio.
Here is the detail of what I'm trying to do:
There are 2 **devices**, 1 & 2, and there is a geofence.
Whenever **device1** enter or exit geofence, a notification will be sent to **device2**.

What I've already did was:
got the geofence set up. A notification will be sent to **device1** locally, upon enter or exit. A FCM is set up, got **device2** token key and is able to send notification to it manually via console (I'm also looking for a way without using the console).

I've tried to do another way around:
install the apps on **device2** and track **device1** location, but after some research it seems to be impossible without installing a child apk in **device1**.

I also tried to search solution but they are either unanswered or it is not the solution I'm looking for (I might be using the wrong keyword or not searching deep enough). So please direct me to a sample code before marking duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: You can do it in multiple way as answered by other developers below(Y) .
I want to add one more way , using #Firebase database.

Comment: I'm using Firebase but I can't do it without a console, and with console I can't seems to find a way to send notification automatically when condition is met.

Comment: process is quite tricky here, #firebase database reflected result real time so to take that advantage, when any data is updated in DB you can generate loacal notification and fetch that data from FDB display it in notification body.

Comment: for ex: there is one table where every devices entry/exit info is updated frequently , now if device 2 data updated (from its enty/exit event) it will reflect to DB and at the same time device1 can get notify. (although I never implement this approach yet but you have to check form your side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, register devices to a topic

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("DeviceRecievers");
```

then send a post request to firebase api  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
//HEADERS
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GB,./,Udno5aA

//BODY
{
  "to": "/topics/DeviceRecievers",
  "data": {
     "message": "Device2 enter blah blah!",
  }
}
```

then handle the result from a class extending FirebaseMessagingService

Check [this](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) as guide in implementing fcm. Hope this helps

Edit:

To set headers

```
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", mAuth);
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

To set post body

```
String str =  "{\"x\": \"val1\",\"y\":\"val2\"}";
byte[] outputInBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write( outputInBytes );    
os.close();
```

Check [this](http://guruparang.blogspot.com/2016/01/example-on-working-with-json-and.html) sample project using httpUrlConnection.

Comment: I've registered the devices to topic. But I couldn't understand the 2nd part of your answer even after reading the Firebase guide. Do I need to setup an App Server first? and where should I implement the code?

Comment: You need to use `HttpsURLConnection` to send a post request, in my case i used volley library You need to use the second part as request body and request header then this  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send as your url

Comment: I followed the HttpsURLConnection from [here](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-post-and-get-request-using-httpurlconnection/)

Comment: Sorry the code is not readable when I post here so I'll just explain what I did.

In the 'String urlParameters' variable i copy paste the whole header and body into it, not sure its the right way to do it but it doesn't work eventually

Comment: Okay after several hour of research and trial & error, I got some understanding. There is no way to send notification directly from device to device. To make it work without using console is to give up using downstream messaging. And to use upstream messaging, an app server is needed, which means I'll have to use an XMPP server. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No you dont, you just have to send that to their API justl ike how i put it in my answer.. I have tried making 2 different apps and send notification to each other by that.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can think you can achieve that with a simple API (rest or whatever)

You setup the geofence of the Device1 instead of sending notification locally, you can call the API to say "Hi i am device 1 and i am entering/exiting the area"

once the API receives this notification from Device1 will need to send the notification to Device2 with something like "Hello Device1 have entered/exited the area"

I don't see how can you achieve that without two APK (or one with different modes/roles) and without an API